# Вывод записей из БД

Tags: php, mysql

В бд есть записи. Скрин:

[image]

Запрос:

```
function get_lang(){
global $connection;

            $query = "SELECT * FROM language WHERE lang='".$_SESSION['lang']."'";

        $res = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
        $langs = array();
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)){
            $langs[] = $row;
        }
        return $langs;
    }
```

вывод

```
<?php foreach($langs as $lang): ?>

    <p class="ministry"><?=$lang['text']?></p>
            <p class="header-text"><?=$lang['text']?></p>
            <p class="header-text2"><?=$lang['text']?></p>

       <?php endforeach; ?>

> при таком запросе из базы выводит три
> одинаковы записи выводяться таким
> образом 1 1 1, а нужно 1 2 3
```

Comment: @LLIAKAJI, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

1. Не знаю, как вам, а мне лично mysqli не нравится. Мне больше по душе PDO.
2. Вот пример вашей записи c PDO:

---

```
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=baseName;', 'root', '');
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM `languages` WHERE `lang`=:lang');
if ( $stmt->execute(array("lang"=>$_SESSION['lang'])) ) {
   $res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}
echo "<p class='ministry'>";
foreach ( $res as $item ) {
   echo "<p class='header-text'>$item</p>";
}
echo "</p>";
```

В данном коде:
1. Создание подключения к серверу БД.
2. Подготовка строки запроса. Здесь `:lang` - параметр, который будет заменяться. Преимущество данного способа в том, что нет необходимости использовать `htmlspecialchars` для экранирования SQL-инъекций.
3. Метод `execute()` возвращает истинное значение, если запрос выполняется, т.е. отсутствуют синтаксические ошибки. В скобках я отправил наш параметр, т.е. PDO сам заменит `:lang` на экранированное значение переменной.
4. Если запрос выполнен, то сохраняем данные из базы в ассоциативном массиве в переменной `$res`.
5-9. Делаем вывод данных для пользователя.

Comment: Мой запрос был неверен изначально для данной цели, мне нужно было из базы БЕЗ ЦИКЛА вытаскивать записи в разных местах из разными ID, нужно было в этом направлении сначала идти.

Comment: мне нужно было из базы БЕЗ ЦИКЛА
не понял ЭТОГО момента

В моем примере идет только один запрос к БД, а в цикле только обработка результата, т.е. в данном случае PDO возвращает ассоциативный массив значений.

Если у вас в сессии значение "ru" - то, соответственно запрос выдаст:
id  text alias  lang
 1    1  zapis1  ru
 2    2  zapis2  ru

Answer (score 0):

Для начала сделайте вывод SQL и посмотрите, то ли вы посылаете:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM language WHERE lang='".$_SESSION['lang']."'";
echo $query;
```

После сделайте вывод сформировавшегося массива:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($langs);
```

А дальше видно будет. И да, что-то странная у вас запись:

```
<?=$lang['text']?>
<?=$lang['text']?>
<?=$lang['text']?>
```

Что вы хотите, чтобы этот код сделал? Он выведет на экран одну строку три раза подряд.

Comment: <p class="ministry"><?=$lang['text']?></p>
<p class="header-text"><?=$lang['text']?></p>
<p class="header-text2"><?=$lang['text']?></p>

в каждый свой блок записывается, идея в том что бы из каждого алиаса вытаскивалась запись которая соответствует $_SESSION['lang']